# odoo res.partner address fields access error on website

Tags: odoo, odoo-website

I am trying to show address fields on website but it gives access error. For some reason I can't use the contact widget on website.

When I visit the page as public user it shows **500 Internal Server error**. But if I am admin, everything works.

In my xml template I wrote following:

```
<span t-field="event.address_id.city" groups="base.group_public"/>,
<span t-field="event.address_id.country_id.name" groups="base.group_public"/>
```

In ir.model.access.csv file I wrote following:

```
access_res_partner,res.partner,base.model_res_partner,base.group_public,1,0,0,0
```

also tried

```
access_res_partner,res.partner,base.model_res_partner,,1,0,0,0
```

But it shows following error:

> AccessError: (u'The requested operation cannot be completed due to
>   security restrictions. Please contact your system
>   administrator.\n\n(Document type: res.partner, Operation: read)',
>   None)
>
> Error to render compiling AST AccessError: (u'The requested operation
>   cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your
>   system administrator.\n\n(Document type: res.partner, Operation:
>   read)', None) Template: website_event.index Path:
>   /templates/t/t/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/span[1]
>   Node: ,

I also tried this in xml without groups, but result is same:

```
<span t-field="event.address_id.city"/>,
<span t-field="event.address_id.country_id.name"/>
```

How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<span t-field="event.address_id.sudo().city"/>,
<span t-field="event.address_id.sudo().country_id.name"/>
```

Please make sure you understand the [security section in the odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html). In my opinion, it is no good idea to give the *base.group_public* group generally read access to your customer data.